# Pass include path from variable with Twig?

Tags: twig

I need to include child-1.twig and child-2.twig in component.twig, and include component.twig in page.twig.

In my page.twig:

```
{% set items  = [
  '{% include "child-1.twig" %}',
  '{% include "child-2.twig" %}'
] %}

{% include "component.twig" with items %}
```

In component.twig:

```
<div class="component">
  {% for item in items %}
    {{ item }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The complexity comes from the fact that I cant modify component.twig, only page.twig. My code above would work if `{% include "child-1.twig" %}` and `{% include "child-2.twig" %}` were rendered but instead they are printed onto the page as a string of text.

Can I do something similar to my approach but make the child include actually run?

Comment: Why can't you modify `component.twig`?

Comment: The file is being consumed by another application also in different instances it will include other child templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I suggest you add an empty block in that file (`component.twig`)

```
{% block includes %}{% endblock %}
```

Then you will be able to do this:

```
{% embed "component.twig" with items %}
    {% block includes %}
        {% include "child-1.twig" %}
        {% include "child-2.twig" %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```